# Resetting golfing flag for unit tests

Tags: go

I have a go function that uses the flag package to parse command line arguments. I want to write unit test for various combinations of args and values, but I am running into the issue.  I can run any one test that tests the function, but when I run the set of tests, I get an error the second time the function is called: "flag redefined".

Is there some way to reset the flag package such that when I make a second/call to flag.StringVar() with the same arg name, the "flag redefined" error doesn't occur?

EDIT:  I am adding an example of code that demonstrates the error.  (This is not the real code structure... in the real code, the functionality is spread across the production code, a unit test function and the reset function.)

```
func broken() {
    var debug bool
    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "enable debug")
    flag.Parse()

    flag.CommandLine.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        if f.Value != nil {
            f.Value.Set(f.DefValue)
        }
    })

    // Error occurs here when BoolVar is called with the 
    // same "debug" string.
    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "enable debug")
    flag.Parse()
}
```

In reality, the code looks like this:

```
type cmdArgs struct {
    debug bool,
    file  string,
}

func main() {
   args, err := parseArgs()
   if err != nil {
        // bail!!
   }
}

func parseArgs() (cmdArgs, error) {
    var debug bool
    var file string
    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "enable debug")
    flag.StringVar(&file, "file", "", "input file")
    flag.Parse()

    if "" == file {
        return cmdArgs{}, errors.New("--file is required.")
    }
    return cmdArgs{
        debug:   debug,
        file:    file,
    }, nil
}
```

The unit tests looks like this:

```
func TestParseArgs_noFileArg(t *testing.T) {
    resetArgs()
    args, err := parseArgs()

    assert.Error(t, err, "error expected, none returned-- 
       file arg not provided, but required.") 
}

func TestParseArgs_withFileArg(t *testing.T) {
    resetArgs()
    os.Args = append(os.Args, "-file")
    os.Args = append(os.Args, "./input.json")
    args, err := parseArgs()

    assert.NoError(t, err, "Unexpected error")
    assert.Equal(t, "input.json", args.file, 
       "args.file value was incorrect.")
}

func resetArgs() {
    flag.CommandLine.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        if f.Value != nil {
            f.Value.Set(f.DefValue)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the flags once and reuse in each test.

Option 1: Use package level variables.

```
var debugFlag = flag.Bool("debug", false, "enable debug")
var fileFlag = flag.String("file", "", "input file")

func parseArgs() (cmdArgs, error) {
    flag.Parse()

    if "" == *fileFlag {
        return cmdArgs{}, errors.New("--file is required.")
    }
    return cmdArgs{
        debug: *debugFlag,
        file:  *fileFlag,
    }, nil
}
```

Option 2: Use a closure.

```
var parseArgs = func() func() (cmdArgs, error) {
    var debug bool
    var file string
    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "enable debug")
    flag.StringVar(&file, "file", "", "input file")
    return func() (cmdArgs, error) {
        flag.Parse()

        if "" == file {
            return cmdArgs{}, errors.New("--file is required.")
        }
        return cmdArgs{
            debug: debug,
            file:  file,
        }, nil
    }
}()
```

It is not possible to clear a flag definition from a flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Set the command line flag set to a new set in each test.

```
func TestParseArgs_noFileArg(t *testing.T) {
    flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
    args, err := parseArgs()
    assert.Error(t, err, "error expected, none returned-- 
       file arg not provided, but required.") 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test different command line arguments against a fixed set of flag defintions, then do the following:

Write a function to reset the command line flags and parse new flags:

```
func resetAndParse(args ...string) {
    flag.CommandLine.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        if f.Value != nil {
            f.Value.Set(f.DefValue)
        }
    })
    flag.CommandLine.Parse(args)
}
```

Define the flags once and reuse in each test:

```
// Define flag once for all tests.
var debug bool
flag.BoolVar(&debug, "debug", false, "enable debug")

// Test with debug flag set
resetAndParse("-debug")
fmt.Println("debug is", debug)

// Test with debug flag omitted
resetAndParse()
fmt.Println("debug is", debug)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Y6uZD5JTyTs

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  However, the reset func you suggest doesn't resolve the error in my particular case.  I am going to add an example in my original post that includes the code you suggest for reset that still throws the error.

Comment: @drhender I assumed that your goal is to test a fixed set of flag definition with different arguments.  It will help if you can explain why you need to redefine flags.  Flag sets may be the solution to your problem, but it's difficult to know without a better description of the prolbem.

Comment: As you assumed, I am testing a fixed set of flags with varying values. I am not "redefining" flags in normal flow, but of course when I run more than one unit test, that normal flow runs more than once.

Comment: @drhender Define the flags once.  Reuse in each test.  I updated answer to match the question.

Comment: That doesn’t work. I am not testing arg values, I am testing a method that parses the args. What you have mixes the production functionality into the test code.